# How to do simple type inheritance

Tags: typescript

How should I structure this code to not have errors?

```js
// Base type
type BaseFn = (arg:unknown)=>unknown

// StringFn is a more specific type of BaseFn
interface StringFn extends BaseFn {
    (value:string):string
}

// NumberFn is a more specific type of BaseFn
interface NumberFn extends BaseFn {
    (value:number):number
}

const stringFn: StringFn = (value)=>value.toUpperCase()
const numberFn: NumberFn = (value)=>{ return value + 1 }

// function that can processes any BaseFn type
const log = (value: unknown, fn: BaseFn)=>console.log(fn(value))

log('a',stringFn)
log(1,numberFn)
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=16&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgMQHZQLxQBRwE4DmAXAK6oDWqA9gO6oCUGAfGZbagLABQ3AlqsAh4AZnADG0AMrA8-AmigQAHoNQATBLEQp0Ab25RDOAG5wANiQhEEMufWu3UBbgF9ufAUNESoAORIAtgBGQgrKqhpaSAr6XEYm5pZEqIEhePYpwUKu3GJUqDZQNrJOaERQ0iXy6FjYphYQjEz1lgB0wFQAqmCQeADC2tj0ufmFmWllfqmhNQkNTbpQeBDAJHjoLdAA1FAAjFBuPFx5BcBQZlQEmHNJUKzUdAA0UMKo5fDRDMwnCFRmEK0LgRsK86olGsMjkDsAByOAwx7FORoSHQ3aPcYzehAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid the problem is to not deal in function overloads (which often introduce difficulties due to co & contra variance) but instead to switch to generics:

```js
type UniformUnaryFunction<T = unknown> = (arg:T) => T

// interface StringFn extends UniformUnaryFunction<string> {}
// also works, but since we don't care about the hierarchy we can just spell this:
type StringFn = UniformUnaryFunction<string>
type NumberFn = UniformUnaryFunction<number>

const stringFn: StringFn = (value) => value.toUpperCase()
const numberFn: NumberFn = (value) => value + 1

function log<T>(value: T, fn: UniformUnaryFunction<T>): void { 
  console.log(fn(value));
}

log('a', stringFn)
log(1, numberFn)

// As a bonus, this is a type error
log('oops!', numberFn)
```

Comment: Thanks for this Sean - this was what I was previously doing, but generics introduce a whole bunch of other pain - for example they cannot easily be inferred.  Hence I've been reverting to simpler types.